# double cell button action

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a  UITableView which has a xib file for UITableViewCell.

On the UITableViewCell  I am adding 2 cell data - because I want to implement a two column style. so can't be modified.  The cell is a bit complex has more components too, and  I want to handle the action of buttons UIControlEventTouchUpInside event. It will download something and need to change the button text after task competition from "Download" to "View" for eg.

The problem it would be solved, if I wouldn't handle the multithreading, async stuff, but needed.  So I need to pass the button and an index to the action method, or set a property for the button ( in Java is easy ) but couldn't find it.

The half code looks like this:

```
    [buttonAction addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and need something like this:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button index: (int) index
{

}
```

In other question the index is passed with `buttonAction.tag = index` but if  I chnage that property, than I think it wont work the

UIButton *buttonAction = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:205]; statement anymore at

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Any suggestion how to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `UIButton` class and have properties for all the information you need. Then you add action to your button for TouchUpInside with `@selector(buttonPressed:)`

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(YourCustomButton *)sender  // or id and then you check it's class and cast to your custom button class
{
    // work with sender.yourProperty
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 [button setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setTitle:@"View" forState:UIControlStateReserved];
```

and then work depending on your title: `button.currentTitle`

Comment: +1,I am a bit lazzy to subclass the UIButton, add to XCode component editor, change the UIButton at xib file, and so on, looking for other solution

Comment: One catch in this approach, you have to create the button object using alloc/init rather than `buttonWithType:` method. [From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW38): _It you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly._

Comment: Thank you Amar for valuable comment.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I guess you could use `setTitle:forState:` method. There are many states that can be used ..UIControlStateNormal              ,UIControlStateHighlighted,UIControlStateApplication,UIControlStateReserved

Comment: @Tala I haven't see your comment and found solution, it is identical what you suggested in comment. Please add your comment as new answer( with my code )to get accepted!